# Xamarin memory reclaim issues

Tags: c#, memory, xamarin, memory-management, xamarin.ios

I have used Xamarin for a while now, and I have encountered a very strange issue.

I am able to crash a very simple two screens app. On the first screen, I have a `UIButton` with the `TouchUpInside` event. On the second, I have a `UIImageView` with attached image (from local file).

All I have to do is to move back and forward between those two View-Controllers, all the time.

When I attached XCode's Instruments with Activity Monitor on, I noticed that my simple app reaches ~100MB of memory before the memory gets reclaimed, then its usage drops to ~15MB.

But when I loop navigation long enough, memory reaches over 140MB and the app crashes. I have discovered this behaviour while working on a more complex app. Of course, I am taking all available precautions:

- unsubscribing events on ViewWillDisappear
- nulling the delegates and so on.

Basicly, in my complex app, I have overriden the `Dispose` method in my base class for all `UIViewControllers`, and I can see that the `Dispose` method is called with `disposing == false` on every view controller that was displayed. However, the memory usage doesn't drop.

What is wrong with it?

I would like to point out few things:

- My Xamarin Studio is up to date,
- Crashes appeared while I was testing applications in debug mode on iPhone 3GS iOS 6.1.3
- In simple appplication, the image was a 1024x1024 JPG file.

Herewith some code sample:

```
public partial class SimpleTestViewController : UIViewController 
{
    private UIButton button;
    public SimpleTestViewController () : base ("SimpleTestViewController", null) { }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        button = new UIButton (new RectangleF(0, 100, 100, 50));
        button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(new SecondView(), true);
        };
        this.Add (button);

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}

public partial class SecondView : UIViewController
{
    private UIImageView _imageView;

    public SecondView () : base ("SecondView", null) { }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        _imageView = new UIImageView (new RectangleF(0,0, 200, 200));
        _imageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/image.jpg");
        this.Add (_imageView);
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Disposing " +this.GetType() 
            + " hash code " + this.GetHashCode() 
            + " disposing flag "+disposing);
        base.Dispose (disposing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating an instance of the button / image and storing them in a backing field, and you're not calling `Dispose` on them in your controller's `Dispose`. The Controller instantiated them, so you have to clear them down.

In the example above, you are also not unwiring the buttons `TouchUpInside` event. I'd suggest not using a lambda for this, and actually create a method for it makes it easier to detach later on.

```
TouchUpInside -= this.Method;
```

In addition, you're not removing the image from the view you added it to.

I know you say you're doing these things in the view, it will dissapear, but that's not happening in your example code. Can you provide a fully worked example with these basics taken care of?

Comment: +1 It is in fact imperative to dispose every disposable to free up resources, particularly in a restricted device such as mobile devices.

Comment: OK, but the dispose pattern i c# looks like this :

public override Dispose(bool disposing)
{
if(disposing)
{
_itemToDispose.Dispose();
}

When the object is being finalized, the overriden method Dispose will invoke with disposing equal to false, isn't it? So Dispose wont't be called on _itemToDispose.

Comment: That's why you have to set your _itemToDipose to null outside of the if block after as an extra precaution